# What happens with ownership of GCP project when someone leaves an organization?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api

In my organization, I have written a script bound to a Google Sheet. I know that if I leave the organization and the script is in a shared drive or shared with other people, this will not be a problem because it will just pass the ownership of the script.

But on this script, I had to set up a standard GCP project to be able to use Google AppScript API with credentials and so on. I created this GCP project using my account within the organization.

My question here is what happens with this GCP project once I leave the organization? Will the ownership also be passed? What about the credentials? What changes will need to be made to make sure that the script doesn't stop working?

Answer (score 3):

This depends upon who is owner and if it was created with a work email account.

If you have a work email account then someone on the domain will have access to your account and be able to take it over.  If they dont well that's their loss, and this becomes a problem often.

If its your personal account and the company does not remove your access and no one bothers to accept your passing it to them.  Then you still have access.  I still have access to something from a company that fired me four years ago and it's still running because i can see the analytics data but no one has accepted access when i tried to pass it to them and my emails have gone unanswered.

Comment: Everything created with a work account from within Google suite. The take over of scripts and folders in Google Drive etc happens automatically or the admin of the G Suite accounts need to do it manually somehow?